# Number of palindromic numbers less than a power of $10$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation, palindrome

I noticed that every $10^{n}$ there is a certain number of palindromic numbers that I collected in this sequence:
$$S=\{a_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2}...\}=\{10,9,90,90,900,900...\}$$
where every number $a_n$ is the number of palindromic numbers between $10^{n}$ and $10^{n+1}$ starting with $n=0$. Now I wanted to know the number of palindromic numbers less than $10^p$ and I came up with this formula: 
\begin{cases}
1+\sum^{\lfloor{\frac{p}{2}\rfloor}}_{k=0} 18 \cdot10^k & {\text{if $p$ is even}}\\
1+\left(\sum^{\lfloor{\frac{p}{2}+1}\rfloor-1}_{k=0} 18 \cdot10^k\right)- \left(9 \cdot 10^{\lfloor{\frac{p}{2}+1}\rfloor-1} \right) & {\text{if $p$ is odd}}
\end{cases}
Is this right?
Thanks! :)

Comment: This is OEIS sequence [A050250](https://oeis.org/A050250). Also see [Number of palindromes less than $10^9$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/994307/318073), and [Number of n-digit palindromes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287582/318073), and [Palindromes of Length Less Than or Equal to N](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/681200/318073).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula almost looks correct, but note the first two terms in your sequence are $10$ and $19$, which are not divisible by $9$, whereas your formula is always divisible by $9$ so your formula isn't quite correct. Also the summation part should be up to $k = \lceil{p/2}\rceil$ instead of $p$.

Comment: Yah that's exactly what I actually wrote in my paper but I forgot to write it in the Equation. I'll edit Thanks!